# Excel Lookup Help

Tags: excel

I would like to know how to perform the following lookup in Excel (Version = 2007) ...

The first sheet (sheet1) has the following 2 columns

```
UserID                            CreationDate
0004F9B41DEB7BED80257808003A2D45    29/12/2010 10:36
0074ACD71905583A80257730001EB114    28/01/2011 10:21
00799CCE1BEA0ACB802577AE00588A88    08/01/2011 15:36
009AD15E65AAB6008025783D00746A8B    20/02/2011 21:18
```

The second sheet (sheet2) has the following 2 columns

```
UserID                              BookingDate
003561E36C682DBE802576C1004A5962    13/01/2011 10:12
003561E36C682DBE802576C1004A5962    13/01/2011 07:51
0051D119847371F1802576210035B302    15/01/2011 12:28
005FF7CD6C0416E38025760D006B81C7    22/02/2011 12:07
005FF7CD6C0416E38025760D006B81C7    22/02/2011 09:33
005FF7CD6C0416E38025760D006B81C7    22/02/2011 09:28
```

What I need to do is take a userID from the first sheet and find out if its present on the second sheet BUT I need to only find ones where the BookingDate on sheet2 is after the CreationDate on sheet1. I don't need any information / columns from the second sheet - just a TRUE would be perfect.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula for cell `Sheet1!C2`, copy down as far as required

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),FALSE,IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)>B2,TRUE,FALSE))
```

Comment: Works like a DREAM ... thanks - you just saved me a whole lot of effort !